# Re-Render the component after array is set react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dropzone

I'm using React with a functional component and Typescript. I've used react-dropzone for file upload so that it has a drag and drop functionality. My code is something like this:

```
<div>
   <Dropzone onDrop={acceptedFiles => uploadImages(acceptedFiles)} accept='image/*' multiple={true} >
      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      Drag or <a>Browse</a> file to upload
      <i className="icon-upload"></i>
</div>
)}
</Dropzone>
<div className="uploaded-images"> ------------------ 1
   {appImages.length > 0
   ? appImages.map((file, i) => (
   <div key={i}>
      <span>{file.name}</span>
   </div>
   ))
   : []}
</div>
</div>

function uploadImages(files: any) {
    const imageArray = [];
    if (files.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        imageArray.push(files[i]);
      }
      setAppImages(imageArray);
    }
  }
```

So the uploadImages function is getting called but the rendering of div for the name of the file( or point 1) is not happening. After doing some debugging I found that after calling the div (point 1) it is calling the uploadImages function. So if do something else no that page then those file names is appearing.

So How can I re-render this component or any other solution?

Comment: I tested your code and it is working, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gbh6bn, so the problem should be in other part of your code

Comment: problem is solved what I did is in uploadImages method setAppImages([...imageArray]); added spread operator

Comment: It is good that you solved the problem, but for me it worked without the spread operator